# how to manage virtual tree structure in a Zip/7z/gzip file?

Tags: linux, package

for example, there are two files : /tmp/hello, /tmp/world

i want to create a package that contains these files, but do not add them according to the original path.

inside : a.zip (or 7z, gzip, etc.)

```
/onefolder/hello (is /tmp/hello)

/theotherfolder/world (is /tmp/world)
```

two paths above are local paths in the package a

and it would be nice if i could mkdir in the package without referring some real dirs in the file system.